I can't display an image uploaded to an amazon s3 bucket in a react page
I have an app where a user registers a post with title, a text and an image. The image is uploaded to a cloud storage service (i'm using cloudinary), and the generated url is used to display the image in my front-end with react. I am having trouble in the display part.
Initially i tried to upload the image directly from the server (i'm using nodejs and express), getting the request body as a multiform-data and getting the file using multer.
app.post('/upload', upload('file'), async (req, res) => {
  const uploadResult = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, {
    folder: "my_folder"
  })
  
  // save uploadResult.secure_url with the post in database
})

It worked at first in my machine, but when i tried my API in an aws Lambda function, i got the error: Invalid image file
Then i tried to send the image to an S3 bucket first, then send to the cloudinary from a signed URL
  async function generateSignedUrl(bucketName, objectKey, expiresIn){
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: objectKey,
    });

    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn });

    return signedUrl;
  }

  app.post('/upload', uploadS3('file'), async (req, res) => {
    async function uploadImage(bucket, s3FileUrl, cloudinaryFolder) {
      const imageKey = extractKeyFromUrl(s3FileUrl); // little function only to get the last item of the URL

      const urlS3 = await generateSignedUrl(bucket, imageKey, 60 * 5);

      const cloudinaryUrl = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(urlS3, {
        folder: cloudinaryFolder,
      });

      return cloudinaryUrl;
    }

    const cloudinaryUrl = await uploadImage(
      "my_bucket",
      req.file.location,
      "my_folder"
    );

  // save in the database the cloudinaryUrl.secure_url
}

this is the middleware using the lib multer-s3 from npm
const uploadS3 = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'my_bucket',
    acl: 'public-read',
    key: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString() + '-' + file.originalname);
    },
  }),
});

Thing is it works when i start the express server in my machine, when i deploy it to aws, it stops working no matter what. How can i display the images correctly, either using cloudinary, or only the s3, doesn't matter, the images have to be stored in the cloud, and publicly available for the front-end.
